Flask Application in Google Cloud Run Not Returning a Response
I've got a Python Flask application deployed as a Google Cloud Run service, which listens on port 8080 for incoming requests. Most requests I make to this endpoint return the expected output, however, when I pass specific URL parameters that make the function run for much longer (from around 5-10 minutes to 20 minutes), the application does not return a response to the client. The client is a simple requests.post() function:
        response = requests.post(
            f'{service_url}/run',
            headers={
                'Authorization': f"Bearer {self.bearer_token}", 
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'x-environment': 'production'
            }
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response

I have confirmed that the function itself runs successfully, and also that the print('Finished!) line runs from the logs. There are no errors returned. I have also confirmed that the timeout in Cloud Run is set to more than enough - 3600 seconds/1 hour
I've tried running the application locally and cannot reproduce, so it's something to do with Cloud Run.
Anyone got any ideas? I'm at a total loss. The task that makes this request is part of a bigger job that has downstream dependencies, so running asynchronously (eg. using threading to return a response to the client whilst the operation runs in the background) is something I would rather avoid.
@app.route('/run', methods=['POST'])
def run():
    // My long-running single threaded function is here

    if is_error:
        status_code = 500
    else:
        status_code = 200
    response = make_response(result, status_code)
    print('Finished!')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)


I don't how about Google Could but usually web servers (like Apache, Nginx) have only 30 seconds to generate response - if it takes longer then they can kill this process. It is method to stop hacker attack DDoS. If you have longer task then you can use Celery to run code as separated thread - and it gives you unique ID which you can later use to check if process is finished and to get result - but this needs to create extra code for this. Eventually it needs JavaScript if you want to display progressbar on page.

Background Tasks with Celery — Flask Documentation (2.3.x)

Can you share how you perform your long running function? Can you also share the Cloud FUnction configuration? And how long it takes on your computer
